# KonvaJS two finger pan and zoom on Mac

Tags: vue.js, konvajs, vue-konva

I'm using KonvaJS (more specifically `vue-konva`), and recently I've switched to a Macbook. I'm trying to implement two finger scrolling and panning. I already have the `mousemove`/`mouseup`/`mousedown` event and that works with one click panning.

I already tried `gesture[start/change/end]` events but that didn't work. For the two finger zooming, I know I'm gonna have to pair it with another key, but that's not working as well.

When I was using a mouse, the `@wheel` event attached to the stage worked fine.

Any ideas? (Ideally I would like this to work specifically on Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the wheel event worked fine, but I had to attach it to the document itself.
Also, since I wanted to only trigger that while also pressing Control, I also added a `keydown` and `keyup` events.